# setting up nexmo test messaging for classified listings

Tags: vonage

Here is what I am looking to setup & I'm wondering if it is possible:

I have a classified ads site where people can join the site and then are allowed the ability to email any listing. I would like to add the ability for people to text message listings as well.

Listing owners would add their cell numbers if they would like to be contacted via text message, the site would then allow user to text BUT it would not show real phone numbers, each listing owner would be assigned a nexmo number and if they choose to give out their phone numbers, they can.

Then, I would also like the ability to send out a general broadcast to all users. Is this possible? And, if so, how would I integrate something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Yep all of that is possible with Nexmo you seem to have 3 or 4 separate use cases here so lets break those down:

When your users sign up for your site you'll want to capture their Cell numbers against their account, you might want to use the Nexmo Verify product as part of that signup to ensure you have a correct and valid mobile number.

For users to be able to add listing via text you would need to get a nexmo number for them to send their listing to, that would be one number for the whole site and you could look at the senders number to link the message to an account (from the one you captured at registration) If you don't recognise the sender of a listing message then you'll want to send back some kind of response asking them to register and a link.

For buyers to contact sellers without revealing their numbers this is a very common use case called 'Message (or Call) Proxy' you need to rent a number for each seller (or listing) so you'll need to factor that into your pricing, then you forward any messages sent to the number to the seller, you will also have to implement some logic to handle replies and track state in your application, within SMS there is no concept of a reply so each message has no association with the previous one, this is a bit tricky when you have several conversations going on over the same number.

Finally the 'broadcast' this would just be a case of iterating over the list of numbers you have for your users and sending the message to each one, you will need to ensure that you comply with any regulations around sending of bulk messages in the country you are sending to, more details for that are on the nexmo knowledgebase https://help.nexmo.com/hc/en-us